# Disc film cameras that use replacable batteries?

Tags: film

I have some [Disc Film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_film) in the fridge that I would like to use, that I got from a film lot.

It seems unlikely that anything amazing will come out of it, but experimenting is part of my process and some recent results [look really cool](https://www.flickr.com/photos/tony_kemplen/5684597020/).

I found a lab that processes it, but I don't own a Disc camera. They seem to cost a dime a dozen on second-hand marketplaces, however, I recall from using one in the past that the batteries are usually not removable by the user, to save space and make a thin camera (they are welded inside the body) - and therefore, batteries from this period might have ran out of juice or become damaged if I just bought any such model.

Given that [over 30 different manufacturers made cameras that use disc film](https://camerapedia.fandom.com/wiki/Disc_film), I wonder if some of them were smart enough to design them to use regular, removable batteries.

These types of cameras are very under-documented across the internet.

### Are there Disc film cameras that use regular removable batteries?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118473/discussion-on-question-by-micromachine-disc-film-cameras-that-use-replacable-bat).

Answer (score 2):

I found at least one: the [Keystone 1040 Everflash](http://camera-wiki.org/wiki/Keystone_Everflash_1040).  This camera uses a manual film advance (so may even work without a battery), and uses two AA cells to power the flash.  Given there's one, there are probably other Disc cameras that don't even have a battery -- fixed-everything doesn't need it if they give a means to advance the disc to the next frame.

I found this by Googling "disc camera battery" and then manually filtering the hits.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great find and answers my question. Will wait a bit more to see if there are other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

NO batteries required.

Use, *or Modify?*,  a 4x5 Large format film holder so you can attach or tape the film, removed from the cartridge, in the middle of it.  *Assuming it will not interfere with the dark-slide, you may have to remove the plastic center piece  in the disc of film*.

Now use the 4x5 LF film holder in [Pinhole camera](http://www.zeroimage.com/Pinhole_Camera_45_2015_BTN.html) that accepts 4x5 LF film holders. It will expose all of the negatives simultaneously. Make an enlarger negative holder for the film and print it as one photo. Or send it to a lab and have each neg printed and then assemble in the same orientation. *Think outside the film cartridge.*

Or variations on that theme. **Experimentation encouraged**.

**NOTE:** Of course all work with film will **MUST** be done in a dark room, **I.E.** A room with **absolutely no light**.

No affiliation with the zero image camera i linked to other then i own one and love it. (*Another option is to make your own*)

Comment: Pinhole or self-made camera would be an interesting experimentation indeed! But here I kind of wanted to use it for what is was meant to do *first* - to get acquainted with the disc film experience and do a kind of time-travelling photoshoot, stepping in the shoes of past photographers, revisiting their gestures, their mindsets, before I decide to build up new experiences on it. Another idea was to use cameras that can still be used (hence my question) but put new film inside.

Comment: Good on ya.  FYI.You can not get farther back in photography history then Pinhole. ;) Camera Obscura. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_obscura  -  I am ready to take your picture, now hold still for 2 minutes.

Comment: 2 minutes isn't that much - a friend of mine created the Washi film that you can buy on lomography and other websites - asked me to stand still for 8 minutes for some test batches once  Also, an image printed onto a surface by a lens that is millions of years old... the back of the retina of animals who have eyes... some forensics are able to extract this "printed" image to identify murderers sometimes!

Comment: (and for long exposures, let's not mention infrared film that usually shoots through a very dark filter, so yes, art, like love - must be patient).